# Disable all drawers with angular-snap and snapjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, snap.js

I am working in an app that require snap menu for mobile resolutions and mobile device.

I am using [snapjs](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js) and [angular-snap](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js), snapjs by default set two drawers, left and right, I can disable one of this drawers using the service in the angular-snap directive with *snapRemote.globalOptions.disable = 'right';* or using attribute *snap-opt-disable="'right'"* in snap-content element.

I need to disable all drawers in non mobile resolutions (>= 768px), actualy I have a directive that check this resolutions, but I don't know how disable both drawers, left and right instead only one drawer.

This is my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('mobileScreenSwitcher', function ($window, snapRemote) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope) {

                $window.onresize = function () {
                    checkResolution();
                };
                checkResolution();

                function checkResolution() {                
                    var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
                    if (screenWidth >= 768) {
                        // I need disable all drawers at this line                
                        snapRemote.globalOptions.disable = 'left';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my actual html code

```
<div ui-view="navBar" snap-drawer="left" ></div>

<div  snap-content snap-opt-disable="'right'">
  ... content here
</div>

<div ui-view="navBar2" snap-drawer="right" ></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('mobileScreenSwitcher', function ($window, snapRemote) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope) {
      snapRemote.getSnapper().then(function(snapper) {
        function onResizeCallback() {
          var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
          if (screenWidth >= 768) {
            snapper.close();
            snapper.disable();
          } else {
            snapper.enable();
          }
        }
        $window.addEventListener('resize', onResizeCallback);
        onResizeCallback();
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $window.removeEventListener('resize' onResizeCallback);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The following approach has worked for me before:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, snapRemote) {
  snapRemote.getSnapper().then(function(snapper) {
    function onResizeCallback() {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
        snapper.enable();
      } else {
        snapper.close();
        snapper.disable();
      }
    }

    onResizeCallback();

    $(window).resize(onResizeCallback);
  });
});
```